# Could not wifi-hotspot using hostapd to connect android after reinstalling ubuntu

Tags: hot-spot, wireless-access-point

I have just shifted from windows. I could share Internet using wifi hotspot using connectify.

Previously when I was using ubuntu 14.10 I could share net but not now.

`sudo lshw | less` showed:

```
       *-network
            description: Wireless interface
            product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
            vendor: Broadcom Corporation
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
            logical name: wlan0
            version: 01
            serial: e0:2a:82:a7:b9:61
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574) ip=192.168.95.103 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
```

`iw list` showed:

```
Supported interface modes:
     * IBSS
     * managed
```

Previously AP was also supported, but now it is not.

Please Help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had this same issue, do as follows:

1. search for Additional drivers in dash
2. then disable **BroadCom Corporation BCM4313** and restart your computer.
3. then install non-free drivers as `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware linux-firmware-nonfree`
4. restart your computer
5. search for plasma-nm in software center
6. install it and launch it by typing `kde-nm-connection-editor`
7. [how to setup hotspot is on this link](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/share-internet-with-android-ubuntu-1404/)